# Error loading type library/DLL after vs 2017 installation

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-2017, nuget

> Error occurred while restoring NuGet packages:
>   System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x80029C4A): Error
>   loading type library/DLL. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80029C4A
>   (TYPE_E_CANTLOADLIBRARY))    at EnvDTE.Project.get_Properties()    at
>   NuGet.VisualStudio.VsUtility.GetPropertyValue[T](Project project,
>   String propertyName)    at
>   NuGet.VisualStudio.VsUtility.GetFullPath(Project project)    at
>   NuGet.VisualStudio.VsUtility.GetPackageReferenceFileFullPath(Project
>   project)    at
>   NuGet.VsEvents.PackageReferenceFileList.GetPackageReferenceFiles(Project
>   project)    at NuGet.VsEvents.PackageReferenceFileList..ctor(Solution
>   solution)    at
>   NuGet.VsEvents.PackageRestorer.BuildEvents_OnBuildBegin(vsBuildScope
>   Scope, vsBuildAction Action).

I have vs2013 installed and it was working perfectly, once i install vs2017, i get this error each time i build the solution using vs2013 and vs2017.

i have tried so many solutions which are provided on the same forum  and none was successful, please let me know if some one knows about this problem and knows how to solve this issue.

Comment: @LeoLiu-MSFT i have not yet resolved this issue.

Answer (score 0):

> Error loading type library/DLL after vs 2017 installation

According to the error messages, it seems that the Visual Studio installation file has been corrupted. To resolve this issue, you can try following methods:

- Launch the Visual Studio Installer, switch to **Individual components**->**code tools**, uncheck the checkbox **NuGet package manager**, click the **Remove** button on the Removing components windows:

  [image]

  Then close Visual Studio Installer, and re-Launch the Visual Studio Installer, reinstall the NuGet package manager by clicking that checkbox.
- If above not resolve your issue, please try to repair Visual Studio 2017 or reinstall it.

Hope this helps.